# Two XML files but one not showing in application when its running

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

I have created a new xml file in the res>layout forlder called tabs.xml. It has the following code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Network"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:text="Channel Type:"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/urbanButton1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                        android:text="Urban" />

                     <RadioButton
                         android:id="@+id/suburbanButton2"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/urbanButton1"
                         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/urbanButton1"
                         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                         android:text="SubUrban" />

                     <RadioButton
                         android:id="@+id/ruralButton3"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/suburbanButton2"
                         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/suburbanButton2"
                         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                         android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                         android:text="Rural" />

                     <TextView
                         android:id="@+id/textView2"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_below="@+id/urbanButton1"
                         android:text="Characteristics of Channel:"
                         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                     <TextView
                         android:id="@+id/textView3"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/suburbanButton2"
                         android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                         android:text="Medium Text"
                         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                     <CheckBox
                         android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
                         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ruralButton3"
                         android:text="Manual Override" />
                 </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/power"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Connectivity"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Offline"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                </RelativeLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>`enter code here`
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now i also have a andoid activity_main.xml in the same folder which i added nothing to it. i also created a java file called Tabs.Java and put it in the src folder under src>com.example.qosmetre>Tabs.Java with the following code

```
package com.example.qosmetre;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
public class Tabs extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabs);
    }

}
```

Now my question is, when i run my app on the terminal or in debugging mode, how come nothing is showing up but a blank screen? Like i want the tabs to show up first thoing with all the stuff underneath them as shown in the code. Also how would i import a library for scatter plotting data that would be in my app?

I need to know where and what files to put what code in because im just a beginner and i dont know too much so ill need big guidence.

Thanks again in advance.

My android Manifest.xml has the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.qosmetre"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.qosmetre.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  <activity 
        android:name=".MyTabsActivity" 
        </activity> 
  </application>`enter code here`

</manifest>
```

Comment: Below `</activity>` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, add `<activity android:name=".MyTabsActivity" </activity>`.

Answer (score 0):

For details, please refer to [TabActivity Android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html).

### Deprecated:

> `TabActivity` is **deprecated since API level 13**.
>
> For apps developing against HONEYCOMB or later, tabs are typically presented in
>   the UI using the new ActionBar.newTab() and related APIs for placing
>   tabs within their action bar area.

### Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

### `tabs.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/Network"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="Channel Type:"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/urbanButton1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                    android:text="Urban" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/suburbanButton2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/urbanButton1"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/urbanButton1"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="SubUrban" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/ruralButton3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/suburbanButton2"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/suburbanButton2"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:text="Rural" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/urbanButton1"
                    android:text="Characteristics of Channel:"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/suburbanButton2"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                    android:text="Medium Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ruralButton3"
                    android:text="Manual Override" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/Power"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/Connectivity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/Offline"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

### `MyTabsActivity.java`:

```
package com.example.qosmetre;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class Tabs extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabs);

        // we start adding the tabs programmatically
        TabHost mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Network")
                .setContent(R.id.Network));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Power")
                .setContent(R.id.Power));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Connectivity")
                            .setContent(R.id.Connectivity));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab4").setIndicator("Offline")
                .setContent(R.id.Offline));

        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0); // sets default tab
    }
    // more methods
}
```

### To answer your question in the comment below:

> "i basically want 4 tabs with different names, and then in each of
>   those tabs i want different textboxes, checkboxes and etc as well as
>   graphs. Keep in mind that the tabs will not have the ame stuff inside
>   them"

You are *programmatically* adding the tabs. If you want to attach the whole `layout`, define the layout (e.g. within `LinearLayout`, `FrameLayout`, etc), then *programmatically* add them in your `.java` code.

Your `tabs.xml` have the following structure:

[image: Structure Chart]

As you see from the above structure chart, your xml code has objects (e.g. TextView, RadioButton, etc) only in `<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/Network" </>`. Please add objects you'd like to display in other `RelativeLayout`s (i.e. Power, Connectivity, and Offline).

One you add the objects for all other three `RelativeLayout`s, you must write the codes that *sets* to the tab within your `.java` code. For example, the following code *sets* `<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/Network` to `tab1`.

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Network")
            .setContent(R.id.Network));
```

Please repeat the above and add all four tabs accordingly. You can replace `Network` and `R.id.Network` to other tab names (e.g. `Power` and `R.id.Power`).

Comment: it says the method gettabHost() is undefined for the type MainActivity. and what do you mean by 'enter code here' . i dont know what code to enter there. Sorry for being so noob

Comment: @user2159721 I modified my answer. Could you try again?

Comment: yeah there are. is there any way i could send a screenshot?

Comment: should it be tabs extends tabactivity or tabs extends activity

Comment: Please add your import statements: `import android.app.TabActivity;`

Comment: so in Tabs.java there is :

Comment: package com.example.qosmetre;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
public class Tabs extends TabActivity {
 then whatever the person above wrote

Comment: after i import the tabactivity it says it is deprecated and in the public class tabs extends TabActivity, TabActivity is crossed out

Comment: then at mtabHost, it says Multiple markers at this line
 - The method getTabHost() from the type TabActivity is 
  deprecated
 - mTabHost cannot be resolved to a variable
 - mTabHost cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: @user2159721 I've updated again. Please check. Thank you for waiting :)

Comment: im checking now, but TabActivity still seems to be crossed out and underlined in yellow

Comment: it still doesnt show up in my application. So for my MainActivity.java file i have just what was inside it when i started this project. and in the MyTabsActivity.java file i put what you said above, and in the tabs.xml file i have what is above in there

Comment: @user2159721 Could you update your question with your `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: what do you suggest i do? i would like to implement the proper way of doing it, but dont know where to put what

Comment: i basically want 4 tabs with different names, and then in each of those tabs i want different textboxes, checkboxes and etc as well as graphs. Keep in mind that the tabs will not have the ame stuff inside them

Comment: i imported achartengine, but have no idea how to use it. Also, i know there is sample code that i could use for achartengine, but i dont know where to find it and where to actually implement the code and how to import it into eclipse.

Comment: you guys are very good people by the way thanks so much for everything

Comment: @user2159721 Once again, I've updated my answer. This is as far as I can help regarding `TabActivity`. Regarding `achartengine`, you may want to ask the question in a new thread as it is irrelevant topic to `TabActivity`.

Comment: im just wondering why i cant see any of this when i run my application? is it because the tabs.xml isnt the main xml file?

Comment: @user2159721 In your `MainActivity.java`, you must set `Intent intent = new Intent(this, Tabs.class);` and `startActivity();`  to call the `MyTabsActivity.java`. Of course, you must add the `MyTabsActivity.java` within your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: @user2159721 The tabs don't *have to* be added within your `MainActivity.java`.

Comment: sorry melv for soo manyquestions but i cant follow properly. i tried writing what you told me but it doesnt seem to work. and i cant seem to add the MyTabsActivity.java to the androidmanifest.xml either. Sorry this is just really important to me and a little more help would greatly be appreciated

Comment: @user2159721 Within your `AndroidManifest.xml`, you must add `MyTabsActivity` if your application calls `MyTabsActivity` through `intent`. For example: `<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MyTabsActivity" </activity>
    </application>`

Comment: @user2159721 You must declare all the activities you call through application cycle in `MainActivity.xml` as above.

Comment: @user2159721 If your problem persists and if your question is not strongly related to your original question, you may want to localize your problem and post it in new thread. That way, you will attract more people to help your problem.